# Expo:Upload to Apple App Store "Skip waiting for build processing"

Tags: ios, react-native, expo, react-native-ios

After a successful upload of an Expo iOS build to the Apple App Store using `expo:upload`, some of the output are:

> ...
>
> Successfully uploaded the new binary to App Store Connect
>
> Skip waiting for build processing
>
> This means that no changelog will be set and no build will be distributed to testers

**Question:** Since we have a message *Skip waiting for build processing*, is it possible to let Expo wait until the build processing by Apple App Store is finished?

*Using Expo SDK 35, `expo-cli` v3.2.3 on Mac OS X Mojave 10.14.6*